# Is advanced visual programming possible in pure HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

I saw just two examples:

[one](http://mrdoob.com/projects/harmony/#longfur) and [two](http://www.yvoschaap.com/chainrxn/)

I've been told that those effects are demos for **pure** HTML5 but is it really so?! Is there a way to code such cool stuff using **only** HTML5? Or do we still need to rely on JavaScript?

Furthermore, someone told me that one can build a solution using HTML5 and then compile it into Android and IOS at the same time. Is that correct?

I seem to have hard time finding info on the advanced part of HTML5. I only see Canvas tag in, Frameset tag out etc... What do i miss?

Comment: I think your title's wording is misleading.

Comment: I see that too now. How should i reformulate it? Tired like a dog... Can't think straight...

Comment: Your first example uses JavaScript quite a bit.

Comment: You could have answered the first part of your question by just looking at the page source.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak That's what i thought but my friend was so sure and frankly i didn't got his explanation for the script references in the code. Just because we refer to JS, it doesn't mean the effect **have** no rely on them, he said. *Now i feel du'h...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything gets labeled as HTML5 nowadays, even those things that have nothing to do with HTML5. So watch out for the hype. There are some amazing things I've seen done with CSS alone but that's not HTML5. Neither is Javascript. Don't be fooled. Read the source.

Comment: HTML5 is a catch-all definition for new HTML elements, CSS3, new JS APIs and WebGL (and more) and it's perfectly acceptable to use it like that, even though it's not 100% technically correct. There's no point in hair-splitting over HTML5.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa - The W3C and browser people I hang with cringe at that so it's not perfectly acceptable and confusing at best. Don't confuse people. Technically incorrect is still incorrect. Don't do that. If someone wants help with HTML5, but they really want help with WebGL, that's not helpful.

Comment: if 90% of people refer to those technologies as HTML5, then you just have to learn to live with it. Everybody understands what is meant when they read the details and those who get upset should loosen up and focus on making good products instead of complaining about people misusing a term that is widely accepted as an umbrella term.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa - You assume too much. Mis-applying technical terms is dangerous and keeps you in the dark. This is an amateur's error.

Comment: Are you kidding me? HTML5 has always been used as a buzzword or an umbrella term by everybody, including Google, Apple and others. You lost this battle long time ago. It's much more unprofessional being unable to understand terms that everybody uses.

Answer (score 0):

No. HTML5 doesn't do much on its own.

From http://mashable.com/2011/03/17/javascript-html5/:

```
Although HTML5 is its own standard, the power of HTML5 is really 
only best realized with the use of CSS 3 and JavaScript.
```

Though as others have mentioned, it's very common (in fact, I'd say more often than not) that the term "HTML5" connotes its use with all the other technologies, and not the standard in isolation.